# Issues recreating a material design lists with leave behind in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-recyclerview

I'd like to recreate the Material Design [list: controls](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists-controls.html#lists-controls-types-of-list-controls) in Android inside a sliding panel.

[image: Material Design list with right reveal mockup from the Material Design guidelines]

I'm making use of:

- com.android.support:appcompat-v7
- com.android.support:support-v4
- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7
- com.android.support:design
- https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel
- https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager
- https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout
- https://github.com/tmiyamon/gradle-mdicons

I ended up using portions of the support libraries, but this specific app is 5.0+ only so there may be some Lollipop-only stuff in my code.

Here is the layout for a list item in my RecyclerView:

```
<com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_floating"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="..."/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
```

And this is the current result.

[image: App example with no dividers and one revealed list item]

The remaining problems to solve are elevation shadows and dividers.

As you can see in the image there are somewhat reasonable shadows on the sides of the list items. However there are no elevation shadows on the bottom of the items, so when an item is revealed no shadow shows above the revealed area.

The second issue is dividers. I have a single-item list with no icons/images so the proper design is to use dividers for the items.

However I can't use the DividerItemDecoration from serso/android-linear-layout-manager because it is not integrated into the slider and this happens when 2 adjacent items are slid.
[image: App example with dividers and two revealed list items]

Does anyone know of any drawable, attribute, or library I should be using to style these list items as material sheets with elevation shadows and borders?

Comment: did you found an answer for this I have literally 0 documentation for google's recommended leave behind behavior?

Comment: I like Material Design, and the thoroughness of the design guidelines, but they really need to provide the documentation and tools to implement the design guidelines!

Comment: Did you found an answer? I wanna do this too and none of the below answers are tagged as right =D

Answer (score 0):

**Shadows/Elevation**

For the shadows/elevation to look like that you can use card view with the common trick to make them slightly wider than the screen width ("full width cards").

For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin_horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">
```

In values/dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="card_margin_horizontal">-3dp</dimen>
```

In values-v21/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="card_margin_horizontal">0dp</dimen>
```

**Divider**

And with that you might not need to change the divider, it might look ok.
Otherwise try adding the divider to the view itself (top view or control it's visibility yourself). It can be just a View with height 1dp and width `match_parent` and `backgroundColor` set to some dark grey (or the system divider drawable (`R.attr.listDivider`).

Answer (score 0):

For the divider part of your question I would recommend looking into ItemDecorators.  You can add an ItemDecorator to your LayoutManager and get dividers.  An example of one is [here](https://gist.github.com/lapastillaroja/858caf1a82791b6c1a36) (and there are several out there if you google for it)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class named `DividerItemDecoration.java` and paste the below code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;


public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};

public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;

public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;

private Drawable mDivider;

private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}
}
```

and use `addItemDecoration()`.
you can find full tutorial on this page :

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0):

**Add `android:clipChildren = "false"` to SwipeLayout and RecyclerView.**
Here is the layout for a list item in my RecyclerView:

```
<com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    app:show_mode="lay_down">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
```

Here is the layout my RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

And this is the current result.

[image]